# usage of generic in Callable and Future interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, concurrency, callable

What's the use of generic in [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface?

Consider this code which I copied from https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6:

```
import java.util.\*;
import java.util.concurrent.\*;

public class CallableExample {

  public static class WordLengthCallable
        implements Callable {
    private String word;
    public WordLengthCallable(String word) {
      this.word = word;
    }
    public Integer call() {
      return Integer.valueOf(word.length());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Set<Future<Integer>> set = new HashSet<Future<Integer>>();
    for (String word: args) {
      Callable<Integer> callable = new WordLengthCallable(word);
      Future<Integer> future = pool.submit(callable);
      set.add(future);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (Future<Integer> future : set) {
      sum += future.get();
    }
    System.out.printf("The sum of lengths is %s%n", sum);
    System.exit(sum);
  }
}
```

Integer in `Callable<Integer>` and [`Future<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is not being used. It could be anything else as well like `Callable<String>` and `Future<String>` and code will still work.

I understand usage of Generics and appreciates its usage specially in collections.

Thanks.

Comment: It's so that `get` will return an `Integer` rather than an `Object`, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of `Callable` vs `Runnable` is the ability in `Callable` to return a value (retrievable via `Future` if using an `ExecutorService`). They could have coded it to just return `Object` and make the code cast but then there would be absolutely no compile-time checking. Seems logical to make `Callable` generic to specify the return type so that you don't need the explicit cast and you have compile-time checking.

Of course, due to type-erasure this all goes away at run-time but that does not reduce its value WRT intent and compile-time.

Comment: And, the fact it avoid you to catch checked exceptions

Comment: My bad, it's same logic as it's in collections, somehow I was not able to understand it before. Thanks for answering.

Comment: So why does [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) also carry generics?

Comment: @BasilBourque Runnable is not generic. Notice that in the java doc it is `Runnable` not `Runnable<T>`. As comparison [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

Answer (score 3):

John has a given a correct answer. Just adding the importance of not
ignoring compiler warnings. While compiling your current code the compiler warns you for `unchecked conversion`.

```
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked CallableExample.java
CallableExample.java:22: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
found   : CallableExample.WordLengthCallable
required: java.util.concurrent.Callable<java.lang.Integer>
            Callable<Integer> callable = new WordLengthCallable(word);
                                         ^
1 warning
```

> Integer in `Callable<Integer>` and `Future<Integer`> is not being used. It
>   could be anything else as well like `Callable<String>` and
>   `Future<String>` and code will still work.

Change your class to use `implements Callable<Integer>`

The compiler becomes happy and your code won't work if you start using `Callable<String>` and `Future<String>` everywhere.